# x86 64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am writing a self modifying code.

```
movq      $TARGET_CIA, 0x550(%rax)
```

This symbol TARGET_CIA is undefined initially and at run time I try to copy a 64 bit immediate value to this location. But at compile time this instruction takes the value of this undefined immediate value as 32 bit and when i try to copy the 64 bits, I see the signed extended 32 bits at its place. 
Is there a way to get this undefined symbol treated as 64 bit value?

Comment: Possible same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415184/load-from-a-64-bit-address-into-other-register-than-rax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64)

Answer (score 12):

You need

```
movabs $0x1234567890abcdef, 0x550(%rax)
```

The movabs instruction is required for 64 bit immediates.

Comment: Lol, just noticed this was an necro answer ;-) Anyway, maybe its of use for someone in some time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply run another instruction to grab the second 32 bits.  May not be the best way as I haven't done any ASM for a while, however it WILL work. :)

Good Luck
Luke Peterson