# Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, instructions, immediate-operand

I'm talking about data movement instructions in the x86-64 Intel architecture. I have read that the regular `movq` instruction can only have immediate source operands that can be represented as 32-bit two's complement numbers, while the `movabsq` instruction can have an arbitrary 64-bit immediate value as its source operand and can only have a register as a destination.

Could you please elaborate on this? Does that mean I can move 64-bit immediate value using the `movabsq` instruction only? And only from immediate value to the register? I don't see how I can move a 64-bit immediate value to memory. Or maybe I was mistaken something important here.

Comment: You have to move it to a register and then to memory. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unless your 64-bit value can be encoded as a 32-bit-sign-extended immediate, you have to move it to a register first and then store.  (Or do two separate 32-bit stores, or other worse workaround to get the bytes where you want them.)

---

In NASM / Intel syntax, `mov r64, 0x...` picks [a MOV encoding](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) based on the constant.  There are four to choose from with immediate operands:

- 5 byte `mov r32, imm32`. ([zero-extended to fill the 64-bit register like always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register)).  AT&T: `mov`/`movl`
- 6+ byte `mov r/m32, imm32`. only useful for memory destinations.  AT&T:
  `mov`/`movl`
- 7+ byte `mov r/m64, sign-extended-imm32`. **Can store 8 bytes to memory**, or set a 64-bit register to a negative value.  AT&T: `mov`/`movq`
- 10 byte `mov r64, imm64`.  (This is the REX.W=1 version of the same no-ModRM opcode as `mov r32, imm32`) AT&T: `movabs`, or `mov` / `movq` with a wide constant.

(Byte counts only are for register destinations, or addressing modes that don't need a SIB byte or disp8/disp32: just opcode + ModR/M + imm32 like `mov dword [rdi], 123`)

Some Intel-syntax assemblers (but not GAS unless you use `as -Os` or `gcc -Wa,-Os`) will optimize 32-bit constants like `mov rax, 1` to 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` (NASM does this), while others (like YASM) will use 7-byte `mov r/m64, sign-extended-imm32`.  They both choose the imm64 encoding only for large constants, without having to use a special mnemonic.

Or with an `equ` constant, YASM will sometimes use the 10-byte version even with small constants, unfortunately.

---

**In GAS with AT&T syntax**

**`movabsq` means that the machine-code encoding will contain a 64-bit value: either an immediate constant, or an absolute memory address.**    (There's another group of special forms of `mov` that load/store al/ax/eax/rax from/to an absolute address, and the 64-bit version of that uses a 64-bit absolute address, not relative.  AT&T syntax calls that `movabs` as well, e.g. `movabs 0x123456789abc0, %eax`).

Even if the number is small, like `movabs $1, %rax`, you still get the 10-byte version.

Some of this is mentioned in this [what's new in x86-64 guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20160609221003/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html) using AT&T syntax.

---

However, the `mov` mnemonic (with or without a `q` operand-size suffix)  will pick between `mov r/m64, imm32` and `mov r64, imm64` depending on the size of the immediate.  (See [What's the difference between the x86-64 AT&T instructions movq and movabsq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434073/whats-the-difference-between-the-x86-64-att-instructions-movq-and-movabsq), a followup which exists because the first version of this answer guessed wrong about what GAS did with large assemble-time constants for `movq`.)

**But symbol addresses aren't known until link time, so they aren't available when the assembler is picking an encoding.**  At least when targeting Linux ELF object files, GAS assumes that if you didn't use `movabs`, you intended 32-bit absolute.  (YASM does the same for `mov rsi, string` with a R_X86_64_32 relocation, but NASM defaults to `movabs`, producing a R_X86_64_64 relocation.)

**If for some reason you want to use a symbol name as an absolute immediate (instead of a normally better RIP-relative LEA), you do need `movabs`**

(On targets like Mach-O64 on OS X, `movq $symbol, %rax` may always pick the imm64 encoding, because 32-bit absolute addresses are never valid.  There are some MacOS Q&As on SO where I think people said their code worked with `movq` to put a data address in a register.)

---

#### Example on Linux/ELF with a `$symbol` immediate

```
mov    $symbol, %rdi     # GAS assumes the address fits in 32 bits
movabs $symbol, %rdi     # GAS is forced to use an imm64


lea    symbol(%rip), %rdi  # 7 byte RIP-relative addressing, normally the best choice for position-independent code or code loaded outside the low 32 bits

mov    $symbol, %edi    # optimal in position-dependent code
```

Assembled with GAS into an object file (with `.bss; symbol:`), we get these relocations.  Note the difference between `R_X86_64_32S` (signed) vs. `R_X86_64_32` (unsigned) vs. `R_X86_64_PC32` (PC-relative) 32-bit relocations.

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi        3: R_X86_64_32S .bss
   7:   48 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   movabs $0x0,%rdi        9: R_X86_64_64  .bss
  11:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 18 <.text+0x18>  14: R_X86_64_PC32       .bss-0x4
  18:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi        19: R_X86_64_32 .bss
```

Linked into a non-PIE executable (`gcc -no-pie -nostdlib foo.s`), we get:

```
4000d4:       48 c7 c7 f1 00 60 00      mov    $0x6000f1,%rdi
4000db:       48 bf f1 00 60 00 00 00 00 00   movabs $0x6000f1,%rdi
4000e5:       48 8d 3d 05 00 20 00      lea    0x200005(%rip),%rdi     # 6000f1 <__bss_start>
4000ec:       bf f1 00 60 00            mov    $0x6000f1,%edi
```

And of course this won't link into a PIE executable, because of the 32-bit absolute relocations.  **`movq $symbol, %rax` won't work with normal `gcc foo.S` on modern Linux distros**.  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).  (Remember, the right solution is RIP-relative LEA, or making a static executable, not actually using `movabs`).

---

`movq` is always the 7-byte or 10-byte form, so don't use `mov  $1, %rax` unless you want a longer instruction for alignment purposes (instead of padding with NOPs later.  [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046814/what-methods-can-be-used-to-efficiently-extend-instruction-length-on-modern-x86)).  Use `mov $1, %eax` to get the 5-byte form.

Notice that `movq $0xFFFFFFFF, %rax` can't use the 7-byte form, because it's not representable with a *sign-extended* 32-bit immediate, and needs either the imm64 encoding or the `%eax` destination encoding.  GAS will not do this optimization for you, so you're stuck with the 10-byte encoding.  You definitely want `mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %eax`.

`movabs` with an immediate source is always the imm64 form.

(`movabs` can also be the [MOV encoding](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) with a 64-bit absolute address and RAX as the source or dest: like `REX.W + A3` `MOV moffs64, RAX`).

---

> I don't see how I can move a 64-bit immediate value to memory.

That's a separate question, and the answer is: you can't.  The [insn ref manual entry for MOV](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) makes this clear: the only form that has an imm64 immediate operand only has a register destination, not r/m64.

If your value fits in a sign-extended 32-bit immediate, **`movq $0x123456, 32(%rdi)` will do an 8-byte store to memory**.  The limitation is that the upper 32 bits have to be copies of bit 31, because it has to be encodeable as a sign-extended-imm32.

Related:

- [why we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771323/why-we-cant-move-a-64-bit-immediate-value-to-memory/62772299#62772299) - computer architecture / ISA design reasons.
- [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) (use 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` as an optimization, or RIP-relative LEA for any case except a large memory model where a symbol might be more than 2GiB away.)

Comment: [Load from a 64-bit address into other register than rax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19415184/995714)

Comment: why `movq $0xFFFFFFFF, %rax` not encodable? why doesn't the 5-byte version work?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Because you used `movq`.  To get gas to use the 5-byte no-REX-prefix encoding, you have to do the optimization yourself and write `movl $0xFFFFFFFF, %eax`.  So it's like YASM, and won't optimize that for you.