# How to change a character in a string in assembly x86 (AT&T syntax)

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Im trying to change the character in a string in assembly, by accessing a certain bit in the rdi where the string address is placed. However, it is giving me a segfault. Please help

```
.text 

hello_world:    .asciz "hellothere \n"



.global main

main: 

    movq $hello_world, %rdi 
    movq $0, %rax 
    call printf

    movq $hello_world, %rdi 

    movb $'a', %r10b
    movb %r10b, (%rdi)
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf

    call exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialized static data you want to modify at runtime goes in `.data`, not `.text`.

The `.text` section is mapped read+exec, `.data` is mapped read+write.

Compilers use `.section .rodata` for read-only static data, to group data separately from code.  That sections is linked as [part of the text segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format).

---

If you want to put a 64-bit address in a register, you should use `lea hello_world(%rip), %rdi`

But if that was the problem (truncating the address to a 32-bit immediate from `movq` instead of `movabs`), you'd get a linker error.

So clearly you're linking this into a non-PIE executable on Linux (because you used `printf` not `_printf` (so it's not OS X where `movq $symbol, %r64` will use a 64-bit absolute immediate), and didn't get link errors from using 32-bit absolute relocations for symbol addresses.  [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64)

(On Linux, static addresses in position-dependent executables using the default code model fit in 32 bits.)

---

You can simplify your program to this, for a Linux non-PIE executable:

```
.data    # mutable static data
hello_world:    .asciz "hellothere \n"

#.section .rodata    # read-only static data


.text    # code
.global main
main: 
    mov   $hello_world, %edi  # most efficient way to put a static addr in a reg
                              # in a position-dependent executable
    xor   %eax,%eax           # most efficient way to zero the whole 64-bit reg
    call  printf

    mov   $hello_world, %edi 
    movb  $'a', (%rdi)          # store directly to memory instead of using a partial register
    xor   %eax,%eax
    call  printf

    xor    %eax,%eax     # return 0, otherwise you might as well jmp printf
    ret                  # might as well just ret instead of calling exit since this is main, not _start
```

compiles and runs correctly with `gcc -no-pie hello-mutable.S && ./a.out`, or fails to link with `gcc -pie`.

To build with `-pie` (the default on many modern distros), use `lea hello_world(%rip), %rdi` both times.

---

Of course you could also use `puts` instead of `printf` because your format string has no `%` chars in it.  (Just remove the trailing `\n`.)  Compilers do this optimization when compiling C.  It's more efficient, and you wouldn't need to zero AL.