# Must the first operand of leaq be a memory address and the second operand be a register?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

In ATT assembly language, when using leaq instruction, must its first operand be a memory address instead of a register or a constant (prefixed `$`)? Must its second operand be a register? I got that impression from reading Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective, and have never seen an example different from my guess. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When in doubt, consult the official instruction set reference. Note that a memory address may of course use a register or a displacement (without the `$` as that would be an immediate).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a reference document on the Internet, but I am not sure where it is.

Comment: [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) PS: uses intel syntax not at&t so you have to do some mental work :)

Comment: @Jester Thanks. What kinds of mental work?

Comment: Translating from intel to at&t. E.g. From `[base+index*scale+displacement]` to `displacement(base, index, scale)`

Comment: @fuz, you might want to remove that comment and try again.

Comment: Also flipping the order of operands (Intel is *dest, src* while AT&T is *src, dest*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  While a `lea` with two register operands can technically be encoded, such an encoding is invalid and leads to a `#UD` exception.  See [this reference](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_153.html) or [this one](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LEA.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was encodable, you'd never want to use it.

If you want to put a constant in a register, you should never use `lea`.  `mov $1234, %eax` is shorter and more efficient than `lea 1234, %eax` (absolute address in a disp32 addressing mode).

The only use-case for LEA for static addresses is 64-bit code with RIP-relative addressing modes, like `lea symbol(%rip), %rax` (7 bytes), in cases where `mov $symbol, %eax` (5 bytes) is not usable because you need position-independent code, and/or the address doesn't fit in a 32-bit zero-extended immediate.

See [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64) for more about why `mov $symbol, %rdi` is not the best choice.

---

In 32-bit code, `lea symbol, %edi` is 6 bytes (opcode + modrm + disp32), and runs only one port 1 or port 5 on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs.  (https://agner.org/optimize/)

`mov $symbol, %edi` is 5 bytes ([opcode + imm32 short form with no ModRM byte](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html)), and runs on any ALU port.

Same for 16-bit code: `mov $symbol, %di` is 3 bytes, while `lea symbol, %di` is 4 bytes, with the same execution-port differences.  (Or in NASM syntax, `lea di, [symbol]` vs. `mov di, symbol`, or `mov di, OFFSET symbol` in GAS `.intel_syntax` or MASM.)

---

LEA is useful with base=register addressing modes, though.  Like `lea symbol(%rdi), %rax` if an address fits in a 32-bit sign-extended disp32.

Or for arbitrary shift-and-add usage, like `lea 123(%rdi, %rdi, 2), %eax` to do `eax = 3*edi + 123`.  [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers/46597375#46597375)