# Compiling GAS code doesn't detect -fPIC option

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, position-independent-code

I am trying to compile some GAS code for a project using the GCC gnu compiler. Here is how I am compiling it:

```
gcc -c boot.s -o boot.o -fPIC
```

After I compile my kernel.c file with the `-fPIC` argument, I try to link it with this command:

```
gcc -N -T linker.ld -o Slack\ Berry.bin -ffreestanding -nostdlib kernel.o boot.o -lgcc
```

It comes up with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: boot.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.multiboot' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

This leads me to think that it is not compiling my GAS code with `-fPIC`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you probly need `-fPIE` rather than `-fPIC`. `-fPIE` allows compiler to generate more efficient code but can only be used for code that's part of main executable (not shared library).

Now both `-fPIC` and `-fPIE` are compiler-only flags and are not passed to assembler. You'll need to explicitly use PIC-specific mnemonics in your assembly code instead of position-dependent calls and branches e.g instead of

```
movq $bar, %rdx
```

use

```
movq bar@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
```

(normally to get the syntax I need I just run `gcc -fPIE -S -o-` on matching C snippet).

Comment: The OP is making a PIE, not a shared library; they don't need the GOT or PLT for internal static symbols.  The only change needed is `lea bar(%rip), %rdx`, a RIP-relative LEA instead of a `mov $imm32, %r64`.  (movabs would work to, but be larger and usually slower.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I'll make an update. I think the question should be updated as well.

Comment: Why, what do you think is missing in the question?  It has `-ffreestanding -nostdlib`, and has names like `boot.o` and mentions multiboot.  Also the error message mentions making a PIE executable.  Seems pretty clear to me that the OP wasn't actually trying to make a shared library.  (This is not the first question about this error message when making an executable from asm, either, so I wasn't at all expecting the question to be about actually making shared libs.  Usually it's just PIE requiring relocatable-anywhere code catching people by surprise.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, why not make things more explicit if possible?

Comment: I guess maybe.  I missed that they had actually compiled their `kernel.c` with `-fPIC`, so the code probably does depend on a PLT and GOT unless they carefully used `__attribute__((hidden))`.  You definitely don't want to go through the GOT / PLT for calls / references within the same object.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yup, I developed [ShlibVisibilityChecker](https://github.com/yugr/ShlibVisibilityChecker) specifically for that. Sadly I found that package maintainers usually don't care much about getting rid of spurious GOT/PLT references...

Answer (score 1):

Recompile with `-fPIC` only applies if the asm was generated by a compiler, not written by hand.  It has no effect on how asm is assembled into machine code.

The problem is that your PIE executable can't be linked with 32-bit absolute addresses.  (Did you mean to make a PIE instead of a static position-dependent executable)?

You don't need the full shared-library stuff for referencing symbols in another library or the main executable (like @yugr's answer shows how to do).  Your freestanding kernel may not even *have* a GOT or PLT, and definitely shouldn't use them for internal symbols.

**The only change needed is `lea bar(%rip), %rdx`, a RIP-relative LEA instead of a `mov $imm32, %r/m64`**.  (movabs would work to, but be larger and usually slower.)

Or, if you actually meant to build with `-static` and create an executable that will be loaded at a fixed address in the low 32 bits of address space, you should use `mov $bar, %edx` to get a 5-byte `mov $imm32, %r32` encoding instead of 7-byte `mov $sign_extended_imm32, %r/m64` or a 7-byte LEA.  See also [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64)