# Writing assembly codeprogram gdb

Tags: c

I have written a simple .c program, and tried to convert it by using `gcc -S` and running it with:

but im not sure how to code my program in this format, if anyone could suggest a solution or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186289/discussion-on-question-by-joe-writing-ia32-assembly-code-on-ubuntu-to-run-on-ter).

Answer (score 3):

`/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is the 32-bit dynamic linker; that's why you get the confusing "no such file or directory" when the shell tries to `execve()`.

Use one of these commands to assemble+link 64-bit asm:

- **`gcc -g -static -nostdlib start.s`** (no CRT or libc, static executable).  Use this for your Hello World that uses `syscall` directly, with no `call`s to glibc functions.
- **`gcc -g -no-pie -nostartfiles start.s`** (no CRT, but *does* link libc, making a dynamic executable.  Dynamic linker tricks on Linux allow the glibc init functions to run before execution reaches your `_start` entry point, so you can still `call printf`.  Unlike if you made a static executable that linked libc.)
- **`gcc -g -no-pie main.s`**  (you write a `main` instead of a `_start`, exactly like a C compiler would produce)

Add a `-o myprog` option if you want a name other than `a.out`.

To assemble + link 32-bit code, add `-m32` to any of these.

**Add a `-v` option to see what commands the gcc front-end uses under the hood**, if you for some reason want to invoke `as` and `ld` manually.  `gcc` on your system will know the right paths for libc and the dynamic linker.  These will be different for 32 vs. 64-bit code.

`-g` is there to create debug info, to make it easier to use GDB if you're using source view instead of asm view.  See the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for asm gdb tips.

---

That said, this works on my system, and I think that dynamic linker path is pretty standard for modern x86-64 Linux systems.  It's equivalent to `gcc -no-pie -nostartfiles start.s`

```
as -o file.o file.s &&
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o file -lc file.o
```

---

If you were using NASM or any other method to create a `.o`, pass it to gcc instead of an asm source file.  (e.g. `nasm -felf64 foo.asm && gcc -static -nostdlib foo.o -o foo`).  See also [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain) for a lot more details.

---

[`-no-pie` allows 32-bit absolute addresses to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) in 64-bit mode, so code like `mov     $message, %rsi` (which assembles to `movq $sign_extended_imm32, %r64`, not `movabsq $imm64, %r64`) to work.  [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64)

`-no-pie` also lets you write `call puts` instead of `call puts@plt` or a memory-indirect call like `gcc -fno-plt` would use: `call puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)`.  The linker will take care of rewriting `call puts` to `call puts@plt` when it finds `puts` in `-lc`.

---

There's no reason you should ever write `mov $message, %rsi`: either use `mov $message, %esi` to take advantage of static addresses being in the low 32 bits of virtual address space, or use `lea message(%rip), %rsi` to make position-independent code that works efficiently even if your code is loaded outside the low 32.

If you were compiling C, you'd want to use `-fno-pie -no-pie` so compiler code-gen can take advantage of `mov $message, %esi` and `mov array(,%rax,4), %ecx`.

---

This answer only attempts to answer the question about how to build the code, which the screenshots show.  For reading the compiler output to understand what it's doing, see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).

And in this specific case of `%100`, [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi)